# Probability involving Method of Moments

Tags: probability, statistics, integration

Considering a box containing balls labeled 1 through $m$ from which we sample $n$ balls (hence, a discrete uniform distribution on  $\{ 1,2, \ldots, m\}$ so the probability of picking $x_i$ is $\frac{1}{m}$). We randomly sample $n$ elements $x_1 $, $x_2$, $\ldots$, $x_n$ (without replacement, so $x_1\ne x_2$ etc). Using the method of moments to approximate $\theta$, I get $E(X)=\bar{x}$, so a estimator $\hat m$ for  $m $ can be found through solving  $\frac{\hat m}{2}=\bar{x}$, hence $\hat m=2\bar{x}$, where $\bar{x}=\frac{x_1+x_2+...+x_n}{n}$.

I was asked to find $Pr(2\bar{x}<\max(x_1,x_2,...,x_n))$ for n=2 (since when this is true our estimate for $m$ is clearly incorrect). Of course, this is trivial, since we get

$Pr(\frac{2(x_1+x_2)}{2}<\max(x_1,x_2))=Pr(x_1+x_2<x_1)\cup Pr(x_1+x_2<x_2)=0$.

It's fairly obvious, however, that for values of $n$ greater than 2, this is not the case. In class my teacher mentioned solving for this probability by hand gets increasingly difficult as $n$ gets larger, but it should be fairly doable for $n=3$. I'm just curious as to how one would approach this. I'm not really sure what the joint pmf for $x_1+x_2+x_3$ is (they're not independent, I believe), and also a little confused as to where I would set the bounds on the triple integral that follows. (If its not clear, I'm looking for $Pr(x_1+x_2+x_3<\frac{3\max(x_1,x_2,x_3)}{2}))$

I realize that this is not a practical approach really (the book suggests using simulations for higher values of n to approximate the probability), and that the MOM is not a great way to do this in general, but I'm curious nonetheless!

Any thoughts?

Edit: While unable to actually come up with the proper integral, I used some simulations in R to determine that the proper answer is $\frac{1}{8}$, I'm not sure if that helps anything but I figured I'd put it up here just in case.

Comment: What is $\theta$ again?

Comment: Apologies, $\theta$ is m (the number of balls in box). I'll edit that for clarity. Thanks!

Comment: You could probably do the case n = 3 by hand as well, it seems that with the correct form of the probability you are asking about, it will be a not too complicated double sum..

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y_1 $, $Y_2$ and $Y_3 $ be the ordered sample, i.e. let $ Y_1 = \min \{ X_1,X_2,X_3 \} $, $Y_3 = \max \{ X_1,X_2,X_3 \} $ and define $\{ Y_2 \} $ by $\{ Y_1,Y_2,Y_3 \} = \{ X_1,X_2, X_3 \} $. Then
$$P\left(X_1+X_2+X_3 < \frac{3 \max \{X_1,X_2,X_3 \}}{2}\right) = P(2Y_1+2Y_2 < Y_3).$$
Also, note that for any sample $\{ X_1,X_2,X_3 \} $ of the set $\{ 1,2,\ldots, m \}$, the event $2X_1+2X_2 < X_3$ can only happen if $X_3 = \max \{X_1,X_2,X_3 \}$, which happens with probability $1/3$. Hence your probability is equal to 
$$3 P(2X_1+2X_2 < X_3).$$
This can be found by simplifying the following double sum.
\begin{align*}
&3\sum_{1 \leq i < (m/2-1)} \sum_{1 \leq j < (m/2-i)}  \mathbf{1}_{i \not = j} \cdot  \frac{1}{m} \cdot \frac{1}{m-1} \cdot \frac{m-2i-2j}{m}
\\&\qquad =
\frac{3}{m^2(m-1)}\sum_{1 \leq i < (m/2-1)} \sum_{1 \leq j < (m/2-i)}  \mathbf{1}_{i \not = j} \cdot   (m-2i-2j).
\end{align*}